# Azure Event Hubs REST API: Why specify the publisher in the URL when sending events?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

The Azure Events Hubs REST API documentation for [Send Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790664.aspx) specifies that the request URI to POST to can be either:

```
https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/messages
```

or:

```
https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/publishers/{deviceId}/messages
```

What is the value of using the latter URI template where we specify the `deviceId` for the publisher?

Comment: One reason is that Event Hub can apply [different policies per publisher name](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-overview/#_publisher-policy). According to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251517/selecting-partition-of-azure-event-hub-when-using-rest-api) the publisher name is used as the Partition Key when using the REST API, but I haven't found a good reference yet

Comment: The DeviceID is a very good partition key, which is probably why the REST document shows `{deviceId}` as the parameter name.

Comment: If you promote your comments to an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: Large scale Sender authorization/identification.**

Publisher policy is meant to enable a powerful scenario. Let me explain it.
 We have 2 entities playing their role here:

1. The guy who owns the eventhub (lets say a device manufacturer). This guy is interested in receiving the messages and process them & extract interesting info out of it (like - detect device is ready for servicing etc)
2. Senders (lets say, the (1) guy - manufactures devices and sells them; he embeds code to push events to cloud on a regular basis; so our (2) is the actual device sending events to eventHub).

Imagine you have 100K such devices - sending telemetry data to EventHubs. Let's say, on the EventHub Receiver you are counting how many messages came from each device (and use this to enable a critical scenario - for ex: bill each device based on Usage). Lets look at how these URI's come into play which enabling this scenario:

1. with the Uri1 [https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/messages] - to be able to send to EventHub - they will need an AuthorizationToken. It is impossible to maintain 100k sas keys per device (and EventHubs support at max. 12 SAS Keys). So (1) - the device manufacturer guy, generates one Token for all his devices - using [GetSharedAccessSignature API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.sharedaccesssignaturetokenprovider.getsharedaccesssignature.aspx) & will stuff-in device id inside the message. This token has access to send any message to eventHub. The drawbacks with this approach are, if there is a device2 which finds out how you bill them - it could simply spoof as device1 - by stuffing in a different name. If one device is hacked they will gain access to the entire eventhub. Overall this device has much higher privilege than what is needed and violates [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).
2. where as, if you are using the Uri2 (https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/publishers/{deviceId}/messages) - to be able to securely send to EventHub - the device needs an AuthorizationToken. So, device Manufacturer issues a token specific to this {deviceId} url (using [GetPublisherSAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.sharedaccesssignaturetokenprovider.getpublishersharedaccesssignature.aspx)). Now that, the device has access only to this device specific resource Uri, the only operation this device could achieve with the key EVER - is to **Send to its own url**. In addition to that - if the device manufacturer ever wants to block this device from sending events - it can issue a [revokePublisher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.revokepublisher.aspx) - from which point this device will be blocked. **This is how they can manage security at a per-sender level in large-scale (in order of 100k)**.

I picked device manufacturer just as an example. This feature comes very handy in many scenarios - for ex: **A large cloud service with ~500 machines writing all critical telemetry events** to an eventHubs, a **large-scale website - performing per-customer operation from a client-side script** etc..

HTH!
Sree