# Azure Event Hub : how to create multple partition keys and how to receive that particular partition key data at receiver side using java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

Azure Event Hub : how to create multple partition keys at sender side and how to receive that particular partition key data at receiver side using java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the number of partition count when creating the Event Hub, please see the figures below.

Fig 1. Select the custom create for Event Hub

[image]

Fig 2. Set up the number of partition count

[image]

If you want to send the messages into the specified partition, please refer to the answer of the SO thread [Selecting Partition of Azure event hub when using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251517/selecting-partition-of-azure-event-hub-when-using-rest-api).

For receiving the particular partition key data, please try to refer to the section ["Create a Java project using the EventProcessor Host"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted/#receive-messages-with-eventprocessorhost-in-java) and receive messages with filtering the unused partition key.

Comment: how to create our own consumer groups and how to consume specified partition id at receiver in a consumer group through java code ?

Comment: @sumanth The partition count on Azure EventHubs is between 2 and 32.

Comment: @sumanth For creating consumer group, you can use the [classic REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt652139.aspx) or [REST API with Resource Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt639498.aspx), or directly create at the tab `CONSUMER GROUPS` of your Event Hub.

Comment: @sumanth And you can refer to the [section](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/#event-consumers) to know how to consume in a consumer group in C#, and try to refer to the [section](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted/#receive-messages-with-eventprocessorhost-in-java) to write the Java code with specified consumer group name.